# Xamarin Forms: Tap Event Args Derived Type

Tags: xamarin.forms, f#

I have some code like this that works fine:

```
type App() =
    inherit Application()

    let stack = StackLayout(VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center)
    let label = Label(XAlign = TextAlignment.Center, Text = "Welcome to F# Xamarin.Forms!")

    do
        let tapRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer()
        let handleTapEvent (sender:Object) (args:EventArgs) =
            label.Text <- "Tapped at " + DateTime.Now.ToString() 
            ()

        let tapEventHandler = new EventHandler(handleTapEvent)
        tapRecognizer.Tapped.AddHandler(tapEventHandler)
        label.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapRecognizer)
```

However when I change the args from EventArgs to a derived type like this:

```
type TapEventArgs(someId:int) = 
          inherit EventArgs()
          member this.SomeId = someId

        let handleTapEvent (sender:Object) (args:TapEventArgs) =
            label.Text <- args.SomeId.ToString() + " tapped"
            ()
```

I get the following error when I call AddHandler

> The type 'EventArgs' is not compatible with the type 'TapEventArgs'

Also, If I change the EventHandler like this:

```
let tapEventHandler = new EventHandler<TapEventArgs>(handleTapEvent)
```

I get this error

```
 This expression was expected to have type 'EventHandler' 
but here has type    'EventHandler<TapEventArgs>'
```

Any way to force that derived type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the types are different, and that is what F# is telling you. The type of `tapRecognizer.Tapped` is of `EventHandler`, so when it is invoked it will be of type `EventHandler` ie not `EventHandler<TapEventArgs>` which is a different type. There is no way to change this, and subclassing `TapGestureRecognizer` is also not possible as the class is sealed.

Additionally, the code you posted would be difficult to compile, as it has circular references which F# prevents. `TapEventArgs` requires `label` which is defined in `App`. `App` depends on `TapEventArgs`. It would not be possible to update the UI from `TapEventArgs` instead a function would need to be passed in, or the state exposed.

There is a solution using the `Command` pattern, which allows some information to be passed to the callback and avoids circular dependencies. `TapGestureRecognizer` has a property `CommandParameter` where a value (of type obj) can be set. A callback can be supplied via the `Command` property that can receive that value. Here is the full example:

```
open Xamarin.Forms
open System

type App() as this =
    inherit Application()

    let stack = StackLayout(VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center)
    let label = Label(XAlign = TextAlignment.Center, Text = "Welcome to F# Xamarin.Forms!")

    do
        let tapRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer()
        let handleTapEvent (x:obj) = 
            match x with 
            | :? int as someId -> label.Text <- someId.ToString() + " tapped"
            | _ -> label.Text <- "Tapped at " + DateTime.Now.ToString() 

        tapRecognizer.Command <- new Command(Action<obj>(fun x -> handleTapEvent x))
        label.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapRecognizer)
        stack.Children.Add label

        tapRecognizer.CommandParameter <- 42 // The value to be passed to the Command's callback
        this.MainPage <- ContentPage(Content = stack)
```

Note that casting must be used, because of the way the types are defined in Xamarin.Forms (using `obj` for the property).

Answer (score 2):

F# does not insert downcasts automatically the way C# does (and this is a good thing, not a bug). You cannot pass a descendant type where an ancestor type is expected.

In order to call `AddHandler` you need to insert a downcast manually using the downcast operator `:>`, like this:

```
tapRecognizer.Tapped.AddHandler(tapEventHandler :> EventHandler<EventArgs>)
```

When the target type is already known (like in your case), you can use an underscore in its place to let the F# compiler infer it from the context:

```
tapRecognizer.Tapped.AddHandler(tapEventHandler :> _)
```

Comment: Adding the downcast in the AddHandler method  does not work.  tapRecognizer.Tapped.AddHandler(tapEventHandler :> EventHandler<EventArgs>) throws This expression was expected to have type    'EventHandler<EventArgs>'    but here has type    'EventHandler'

Comment: What's the type of `tapRecognizer.Tapped`?